# Changing elements of list to string

Tags: python

I have a list `[['user44'],['user204'],['user355'],['user395'],['user452']]`

I want to convert it to `[ 'user44', 'user204' , 'user355', 'user395', 'user452']`

Any help on this?

Comment: Your output format doesn't make sense. Do you mean `['user44', 'user204',...]`? If so, then you probably want something like `[l[0] for l in your_list]`.

Comment: If @alani's result is what you want, `unwrapped_list = [x for [x] in orig_list]` will do the trick.

Comment: @ShadowRanger so nice didn't knew that

Comment: The important thing is to understand the differences between the different techniques. What I suggested (also yonatansc97's answer): use first element of each sub-list, silently discard any more; ShadowRanger's suggestion: use the first element, raise an error if there are more than one; balderman's answer: use all elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `userXYZ` is always a string

```
lst = [['user44'],['user204'],['user355'],['user395'],['user452']]
lst1 = [y for x in lst for y in x]
print(lst1)
```

output

```
['user44', 'user204', 'user355', 'user395', 'user452']
```

Answer (score 0):

Every element of the list is a list itself, with one element.
You can take that element and create a new list using list comprehension.
`new_list=[elem[0] for elem in old_list]`

This will go over all elements of the list (which are themselves, lists), and extract the strings into a new list.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow for use encase you need to join more than 1 list.

```
x = [''.join(x[i] for i in range(len(x)))]
```